# Como mostrar uma imagem no tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu quero adicionar uma imagem ao widget, porém não aparece nada, tentei seguir igual dessa cara https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139637/how-can-i-display-an-image-using-pillow , mas não funciona.

Código dele:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bola.jpg"))
tk.Label(root, image=tkimage).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

imagem no código dele funciona:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class TesteImage1:
   def __init__(self, master=None):
      self.widget1 = Frame(master)
      self.widget1.pack()

      self.imagem = Label(self.widget1)
      # imagem = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bola.jpg"))
      self.imagem['image'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bola.jpg"))
      # self.imagem['text'] = "Testando"
      self.imagem.pack()

      self.teste = Label(self.widget1, text="testando")
      self.teste.pack()

root = Tk()
TesteImage1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: As alterações do Elton funciona melhor, porque irei tornar a imagem dinâmica, ou seja, uma função irá alterar a imagem.

def mudarImagem(self):
        width = 500
        height = 500
        amostra = Image.open("bola.jpg")
        self.amostra = ImageTk.PhotoImage(amostra.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.imagem['image'] = self.amostra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vejo dois erros

> O primeiro esta aqui

```
self.imagem['image'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bola.jpg"))
```

oq acontece é que ImageTk.PhotoImage esta sendo pego pelo coletor de lixo, a solução é passar a referancia com variavel

```
self.amostra = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bola.jpg"))
self.imagem['image'] = self.amostra
```

> O segundo erro é o mesmo

o coletor esta pegando a chamada da classe

```
TesteImage1(root)
```

coloque a saida numa variavel e vai funcionar

```
teste = TesteImage1(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de tudo verifique se a imagem que você quer colocar está na mesma pasta do código da sua janela. Eu resolvi seu problema com script abaixo:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class TesteImage1:

    def __init__(self, master=None):

        self.widget1 = Frame(master)
        self.widget1.pack()

        # imagem = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bola.jpg"))
        image = Image.open("bola.jpg")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.imagem = Label(master, text = "adicionando", image = photo)
        self.imagem.image = photo
        self.imagem.pack()

        self.teste = Label(self.widget1, text="testando")
        self.teste.pack()


root = Tk()
TesteImage1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Espero ter ajudado!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]